# Public properties or custom initializers for Dependency Injection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I am working with dependency injection in my apps. I want to develop my apps the best testable as I can. My question here is, why, where and when is better to use public properties or custom initializers. I don't really know the difference and I have listened that big initializers are better than public properties, but I really do not understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is probably off-topic as it is opinion based, but as I see it custom initialisers are better in the situation where the object cannot operate without all of the dependencies in the initialiser as it prevents the instantiation of an object that doesn't have all of its dependencies.

You can then expose the dependencies via properties if there is a need to change the dependencies during the object's life.

If properties are used exclusively then you need to first instantiate the object and then populate all of the dependencies, with the object then left to handle missing dependencies as gracefully as possible.

If an initialiser is combined with properties then you can detect an attempt to assign a nil dependency in the property setter and react accordingly rather than potentially having to check before each use of a dependency.